# how to set mapkit's default annonation location?

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, mapkit, location

I want to pass cordinates to default blue blob of mapkit.but it gives error? how do i show blue blob at my desired location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blue "blob" marker is the users current location marker and is provided by the MapKit framework. It is not possible to set the location of this marker in your code.

See this documentation:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKUserLocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008424-CH1-SW3